# Swift Get previous years datetime at GMT+08:00 timezone

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, timezone

I need to get previous 5 years of GMT +08:00 timezone but I'm having trouble of getting the correct timezone.

```
 let today = NSDate()
    let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)

    gregorian?.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 60*60*8)
    let offsetComponents = NSDateComponents()
    offsetComponents.year = years
    let nYearsDate: NSDate = gregorian!.dateByAddingComponents(offsetComponents, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))!

    println("getNYearsDate: \(nYearsDate)")

I am getting 2010-07-23 11:44:47 +0000 
instead of 2010-07-23 00:00:00 +0800
```

I need to get

2010-07-23 00:00:00 +0800 and 2010-07-23 23:59:59 +0800

is there anyway to achieve this in Swift and iOS 7.1 above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the time as well. Date periods are also best modeled with `NSDateComponents`.

```
// a little trick to get all calendar unit masks
let kAllCalendarUnits = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max)

// normalize the date
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(
                 kAllCalendarUnits, fromDate: NSDate())
components.hour = 0
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
let dateAtStartOfDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)!

// subtract 5 years
var period = NSDateComponents()
period.year = -5
let finalDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(period, 
                toDate: dateAtStartOfDay, options: [])!
```

Note that the method with date components will give you the correct day, regardless if the period contains one or two leap years.

The rest is just a question of how to display this date. This is done with `NSDateFormatter`. Eg.:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 60 * 60 * 8)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"
formatter.stringFromDate(finalDate)
// "2010-07-23 6:00:00 +0800"
```

In case you are wondering why it says "6:00" instead of "8:00": I ran this code with my machine set to GMT+1, plus summer time +1. Obviously, to get "0:00" you have to subtract the desired time difference again, but that would be 8 hours earlier in the GMT time zone.

Comment: Didn't know i need to reset the start day as well. thank you for the detailed explanation.